# prisoner in German, four translations

Tags: difference, noun, vocabulary

I have translated prisoner into German in more dictionaries. I have four translations in total:

> - Häftling (m)
> - Gefangener (m)
> - Strafgefangener (m)
> - Sträfling (m)

Are they all synonyms?

Comment: There are even more. Have a look at the thesaurus here: http://dwds.de/wb/H%C3%A4ftling

Comment: @Takkat it's the first time i ever heard of Arrestan Knastologe ,Sacklpicker and Zuchthäusler. Thanks for that!

Comment: *Arrestant* is not so uncommon (higher level), *Zuchthäusler* is dated, the others are more or less colloquial or regionally used.

Answer (score 8):

They are all related to arrest but may have slight differences in the meaning:

> [Häftling](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haeftling) m,

means a person who's under arrest.

> [Gefangener](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gefangener) m,

may either mean somebody who has been captured or arrested (during war: a war prisioner) or somebody who's under arrest (for whatever reason). So "Gefangener" could also be a captive or hostage, somebody who has been jailed or imprisoned for example by a criminal...

> [Strafgefangener](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Strafgefangener) m,

Is somebody arrested because of a committed crime.

> [Sträfling](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Straefling) m".

Is a synonym of "Strafgefangener".

Comment: prisoner of war is Kriegsgefangener !

Comment: I don't really share Duden's view here - *Prisoner of war* is too specific for "Gefangener", which is anyone who is "gefangen".

Comment: @tofro: Richtig, aber *Gefangener* kann auch *Kriegsgefangener* bedeuten, nicht aber *Strafgefangener*, so dass das ein Unterschied zw. G und SG ist, und das war gefragt.

Comment: @userunknown Ich sehe nicht, dass *Gefangener* nicht auch *Strafgefangener* bedeuten könnte. Wieso nicht - Der ist doch auch gefangen?

Comment: *Hostage* is *Geisel*, not *Gefangener*.

Comment: _Geisel_ is probably a better translation for _Hostage_, but _Gefanger_ is not wrong. And it wasn't about translation. Eine _cow_ ist ein _Säugetier_, auch wenn _Kuh_ die korrekte Übersetzung ist.

Comment: @tofro: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Obst und Banane? Obst kann zwar eine Banane sein, aber Obst kann auch eine Erdbeere sein. Eine Banane kann keine Erdbeere sein. Das ist der Unterschied.

Answer (score 1):

The words you are asking about can be grouped into two classes: one being *Gefangener* and its compound fom *Strafgefangener* and the other being those ending in *-ling.*

## Gefangener

This is basically a nominalisation of the participle *gefangen* and means *somebody who is captured.* Intrinsically, there is no mentioning who (or what) captured him, how he is being captured/restrained and where he is — there is just something there that is restricting his freedom. Of course, this applies generally to everybody in jail but it is also used as a much more general term. For example, you could just have fallen into a trap or the restraining could be an entirely mental thing.

> Als der Käfig von oben heruntersauste, wusste ich, dass ich jetzt Gefangener bin.
>
> Er könnte es tun, will aber nicht. Er ist Gefangener seiner Moralvorstellungen.
>
> Beim Sturm auf die Bastille wurden nur wenige Gefangene befreit.

### Strafgefangener

As stated above, this is merely a compound word and the first component *Straf-* does nothing more than clarify that capturing is a punishment. At least, that is the theory. In practice, this word has become the standard and ‘official’ German German word for prisoner (see its [Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafgefangener)). As such, it is the most neutral but also the most technical term for a prisoner.

> Der Strafgefangene verbüßt eine Haftstrafe wegen Körperverletzung.

### Kriegsgefangener

This word wasn’t mentioned, but it bears being added due to its similarity to the case above. The component *Kriegs-* of course means war, so this person is a prisoner of war. The rest applies analogously.

## Häftling/Sträfling

Both of these words include the suffix *-ling.* In some cases, that suffix has a pejorative function; in all cases it may be perceived as condescending (possibly from a higher moral point of view). Neither of these two words is fully in official usage but both are understood everywhere and used colloquially and in not quite as formal and official settings (e.g. newspaper articles).

### Häftling

This noun derives from the term *Haft.* *Haft* is an umbrella term for a number of different imprisonments with the sole common element of following a judge’s decision. Different types of *Haft* include *Untersuchungshaft, Beugehaft* and what is typically known as *Freiheitsstrafe.* In order of appearance these are *remand,* jail due to *contempt* and standard *prison sentence.* No distinction of the type of imprisonment is made in the word *Häftling.* (Note, however, that before a warrant has been issued the person is *festgenommen,* not *inhaftiert* and thus does not qualify as a *Häftling.)*

> Der Häftling wartet jetzt auf seinen Prozess.
>
> Wegen Körperverletzung werden Sie ein paar Monate als Häftling verbringen.
>
> Weil er seine Schulden nicht bezahlen wollte, wurde er zum Häftling.

### Sträfling

This one is a bit of an odd one out. It does *not* require imprisonment; however, it’s root *Strafe* requires conviction. Technically, a *Sträfling* could also be someone who has only been fined or to somebody convicted but not yet imprisoned, but in common usage it is mainly applied to *Strafgefangene.* Thus, most *Sträflinge* are *Häftlinge* but not all *Häftlinge* are *Sträflinge.* (However do note that this distinction is not always made.)

> Der Sträfling muss drei Jahre absitzen.
>
> Und so wird aus einem (Untersuchungs-) Häftling ein Sträfling.

Comment: Den Unsinn mit der Endung -ling (Liebling, Pfifferling) hast Du von Anatol Stefanovitsch?

Comment: @userunknown Wer ist Anatol Stefanowitsch? Im Übrigen verweise ich auf *may* also *kann haben;* nicht *hat.*

Comment: Das macht es nicht besser. Was soll das für eine Aussage sein, dass eine Endung manchmal eine herabsetzende Funktion hat? Kannst Du andere Endungen nennen, die solche und ähnliche Funktion haben, aber nur manchmal? Lässt sich in endlicher Zeit ermitteln, ob das nun bei Häftling u. Sträfling der Fall ist, oder eher nicht, wie bei Zwilling? Wenn es nicht der Fall wäre, wieso erwähnst Du es dann? Mehr, auch mit Link zu A.S. hier: https://demystifikation.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/fluechtlinge-zu-gefluechteten-sprachlog/

Comment: @userunknown 1. Genau diese. 2. *-ler* *(Hinterbänkler, Tüftler)* 3. Jein, aber das macht auch den Reichtum der Sprache aus. 4. Weil es für das Verständnis mE interessant ist. Über die Genderthese habe des Verfassers habe ich übrigens herzhaft gelacht =D

Comment: Du meinst also das ~ler in Hinterbänkler sei herabsetzend, nicht die Hinterbank? Und Tüftler findest Du auch herabsetzend? Und wie kann die Endung diese Funktion haben, wenn man sich nicht darauf verlassen kann? Ich sage die Hinterbank ist es, die den Hinterbänkller schwach aussehen lässt. Das *ler* zeigt an, dass es um eine Person geht, die mit der Ding des Wortstamms verbunden ist (Sattler, Hinterbänkler, Tüftler). Häftlinge u. Sträflinge sind aus einleuchtenden Gründen geächtet, das bedarf keiner Endung um das zu kennzeichnen.